# Django Full Text SearchVectorField obsolete in PostgreSQL

Tags: django, postgresql, full-text-search

I'm using Django's inbuilt **full text search** with PostgreSQL.

The Django docs say that performance can be improved by using a [`SearchVectorField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#searchvectorfield). That field keeps a pre-generated [`ts_vector`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/datatype-textsearch.html#DATATYPE-TSVECTOR) column with all the relevant lexemes alongside the model, rather than generating it on the fly during every search.

However, with this approach the `ts_vector` must be updated whenever the model is updated. To keep it synchronised, the Django docs suggest using "triggers", and refer us to the PostgreSQL documentation for more details.

However, the PostgreSQL docs themselves say that the trigger approach is now [obsolete](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-features.html#TEXTSEARCH-UPDATE-TRIGGERS). Instead of manually updating the `ts_vector` column, it is better to keep the column automatically up-to-date by using a [stored generated column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-tables.html#TEXTSEARCH-TABLES-INDEX).

**How can I use PostgreSQL's recommended approach with Django**?

Comment: Apologies if I'm missing something here, but wouldn't it be ok to just update search vector column manually with Django/Python each time the document changes? e.g. with an atomic transaction or signal. Instead of diving into migrations and SQL?

Comment: @bsmith4 it's possible, but very inefficient for frequent changes on large documents (which is my use case)

Comment: There is a ["wontfix" django ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31300) where this feature is rejected on the basis that it is a highly compicated subject that needs thorough and in depth analysis of the consequent refactoring of the codebase.

Answer (score 7):

I worked out how to do this using custom migrations. The main caveat is that you'll need to update these migrations manually whenever the base model (that you're searching) changes.

Note you must be using PostgreSQL 12 for the following to work:

---

First, create a database column to store the tsvector:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations my_app --empty

Migrations for 'my_app':
  my_app/migrations/005_auto_20200625_1933.py
```

Open the new migration file to edit it. We will need to create a column to store the tsvector WITHOUT any associated field in the model definition, so that Django doesn't try to update the auto-generated field itself.

The main downside to this approach is that because this isn't synced to the Django model, if the fields change then a new migration will need to be manually created.

```
#my_app/migrations/0010_add_tsvector.py

"""
Use setweight() to rank results by weight (where 'A' is highest).
Use PostgreSQL tsvector concatenation operator || to combine multiple
fields from the table. Use `coalesce` ensure that NULL is not
returned if a field is empty.

In this case, `blog_table` is the database table name, and
`textsearch` is the new column, but you can choose anything here
"""

operations = [
    migrations.RunSQL(sql="""
        ALTER TABLE "blog_content" ADD COLUMN "textsearch" tsvector
        GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
        setweight(to_tsvector('english', coalesce(body, '')), 'A') ||
        setweight(to_tsvector('english', coalesce(title, '')), 'B') ||
        ' '
        ) STORED NULL;
    """, reverse_sql="""
        ALTER TABLE "blog_content" DROP COLUMN "textsearch";
    """
    )
]
```

To create the new column in the database, run:

```
$ python manage.py migrate my_app
```

Then, to use the column in text searches:

```
#my_app/views.py

from django.db.models.expressions import RawSQL
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVectorField
from django.views.generic.list import ListView


class TextSearchView(ListView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        '''Return list of top results
        
        Since there is no model field, we must manually retrieve the
        column, using `annotate`
        '''
        query = self.request.GET.get('search_term')

        return Blog.objects.annotate(
                ts=RawSQL(
                    'textsearch',
                    params=[],
                    output_field=SearchVectorField()
                )
            ).filter(
                ts=query
            )
```

Note that the results will already be ranked, because the weights are applied each time the tsvector updates itself.

Answer (score 2):

A [django ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31300) that requests this new feature has been rejected:

> ...
> Generated/Function-based virtual columns are a huge topic that would
> require many changes and have many caveats, e.g. functions must be
> deterministic. They are feasible also on Oracle. This kind of features
> require few weeks (even months) of works, a precise plan, and should
> be preceded by a discussion on DevelopersMailingList and even DEP.

Some workarounds include:

- Populating the contents of the field in [`models.Model.save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save).
- Populating the contents of the field in [`forms.ModelForm.save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method).
- Using a [post-save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save).

I have found [an article](https://www.netlandish.com/blog/2020/06/22/full-text-search-django-postgresql/) that showcases some coding practices that will keep you going.

Answer (score 0):

Django 5 adds the ability to have a generated field directly
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/releases/5.0/#database-generated-model-field

```py
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import F
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector, SearchVectorField

class Blog(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField()
    title = models.TextField()
    search_vector = models.GeneratedField(
        expression=SearchVector("title", config="english") + SearchVector("body", config="english"),
        output_field=SearchVectorField(),
        db_persist=True,
    )
```